# Help translating some Attic Greek

Tags: greek

I am attempting to translate the following, and I'm feeling completely lost:

> τὸν ἐκείνου φίλον οὐ περὶ πολλοῦ ποιεῖσθε

The best I've come up with is

> not concerning many women you all consider the friend of that guy

If you could break down the form and syntax of the words that would be much appreciated. (I can't quite work out how many substantives are flying around here)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

περὶ πολλοῦ with ποιουμαι in (Middle mood)
is a set phrase meaning **value highly**.
example:

> χρήματα περὶ πολλοῦ ἐποιοῦντο
>   they ...valued money highly.

οὐ means 'not;' the -εῖσθε ending means 'you:'

> οὐ περὶ πολλοῦ ποιεῖσθε
>   you do not value highly

As you have worked out, τὸν ἐκείνου φίλον means the friend of that guy.

Comment: Είμαι Έλληνας και ούτε καν που κατάλαβα.... μονο το πρωτο νομιζω καταλαβα περιπου

Comment: wait, you are greek right?